# Link error on Android

Tags: android, c++, linker, android-ndk

When compiling native code on android I am experiencing a problem :

```
CMakeFiles/test_v_job.dir/test_v_job.cpp.o:test_v_job.cpp:function
boost::detail::signal_handler::~signal_handler(): error: undefined
reference to 'sigaltstack'
CMakeFiles/test_v_job.dir/test_v_job.cpp.o:test_v_job.cpp:function
boost::detail::signal_handler::signal_handler(bool, int, bool, char*):
error: undefined reference to 'sigaltstack'
CMakeFiles/test_v_job.dir/test_v_job.cpp.o:test_v_job.cpp:function
boost::detail::signal_handler::signal_handler(bool, int, bool, char*):
error: undefined reference to 'sigaltstack' collect2: ld returned 1
exit status
```

***signal.h*** header file is in the directory : C:\AndroidSDKS\android-ndk-r7-crystax\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include

**What must be linked?**

Comment: I've tried to link -lboost_signals. It didn't solve my problem. I think   I need to link library which contains 'sigaltstack'. On linux it is libc. Where 'sigaltstack' on android?

Comment: Are you sure it's an **Android** build of libboost_signals? A Windows or Linux build won't be compatible with the Android NDK.

Comment: To build the boost under ANDROID NDK I use http://github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error is caused probably by old platform of android-ndk,it should be compiled with at least android-9 or higher

it has nothing to do with boost libs

for example if you use ndk-build you schould add to Application.mk those lines:

APP_ABI := armeabi
APP_PLATFORM := android-9

Answer (score 0):

To build the boost under ANDROID NDK I use github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android –  e.proydakov